# Visual Studio Navigation Bar Not Showing Overloaded Functions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

how do you enable showing different overloaded functions in the navigation bar in Visual Studio?

Currently I have two functions, one with 0 and and one with several parameters and the navigation bar only displays the function with no parameters by default.

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition